# Is the installation tutorial outdated? Google API novice here

Tags: php, google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample

Trying to run the quickstart.php file i find that it does absolutelly nothing.
Checking the code and comparing it to my files i see the folder and files names are different. I download the library from github and i also noticed the src folder was updated 2 days ago.

I tried just to chage them to make the quickstart run but yet it does nothing.

Im trying to authorize google drive to upload files from a page.
I already got my secret key and id, hello world and all those steps, i just cant make the quickstart to run.

I dont know how to use subversion, i just want to upload files, can somebody help me? what am i missing?

```
 <?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php'; //incorrect files
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php'; /incorrect files

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('already changed');
$client->setClientSecret('already changed');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = file_get_contents('document.txt');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));

print_r($createdFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found this: 
[Submitting file to Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183954/submitting-file-to-google-drive)

The code is indeed outdated, i did these changes:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php'; 
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google/Service.php'; 
instead of Google_DriveService just use Google_Service.
implement the code posted by user3407337 on the previous link.
```

That should do the trick.